# How to elegantly found the content of an NSIndexPath (and other cases) in Xcode 5?

Tags: objective-c, debugging, xcode5

Say I want to know the section and row of that NSIndexPath.

These I have tried:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You are encountering a couple of problems. The first problem - leading to the error "property 'row' not found on object..." - is probably due to using properties declared on an `NSIndexPath` category (`row` and `section` are in the UIKit Additions category). Sometimes lldb is weird about when it will accept dot syntax, this must be one of them. Another issue - and the cause of the "No Objective-C description available" message - is that you are using `po` to print a non-object type - those properties are `NSInteger`s which are primitive types. Remember that `po` stands for 'print object', so only use it on objects. The proper command to print other types is `p`.

Try this lldb command:

```
p (NSInteger) [indexPath row]
```

or

```
expr void NSLog(@"row = %d, section = %d", [indexPath row], [indexPath section])
```

Comment: can anyone verify that this works? I think I tried p [indexPath row] before and it didn't work. Would adding (NSInteger) in front of [indexPath row] works because it's very not natural. And why?

Comment: You can cast it as an `int` instead of `NSInteger` if you want - that's what I usually do. It's something to do with lldb not having visibility of the `NSIndexPath` category that declares these methods.

Comment: So how come adding (NSInteger) fix that?

Comment: @JimThio I believe because it explicitly provides the type information that it can't infer, which enables the debugger to output the result of the expression correctly.

Comment: good point about the UIKit category, which is why the debugger doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 3):

`p (NSUInteger)[indexPath row]`

and the reason is that the debugger doesn't know the return type so it must be specified
by specifying the return type, it is a little bit more than a cast. from the return type the debugger can determine its size, signedness, class(struct, int, pointer, floating point), and where to look for that return value... based on the ABI, the `ints` will be returned in one kind if return register, `floats` likely in another, structs usually on the stack etc.

so in short it knows where to get the data, and how to display it if you provide the return type.

Comment: Hadn't thought about the register / stack differentiation there, good point!